# Appending a React Component to a JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm appending React components to a few JQuery dialogs in an already existing web application. I'm not using JQuery to manipulate the DOM (aside from the initial append to the dialog), I'm letting React handle everything and it's working the way it should right now. When state changes so does the React component inside the dialog. What I'm wondering is, could there be any unforeseen issues doing it this way since the React component is no longer located in the div it was originally rendered in? And also would this be considered bad practice? Here is some example code:

index.js

```
const createStoreWithMiddleWare = applyMiddleware()(createStore);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ createStoreWithMiddleWare(reducers) }>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

App component

```
export default class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return(
           <div>
               <ChatWindow />
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

ChatWindow component

```
class ChatWindow extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div id="ChatContainer">
          <div className='ChatMenu' id="MainChat">
            <UserList></UserList>
            <ChatMessageView></ChatMessageView>
            <UserInput></UserInput>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
 }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.createDialog();
  }

  createDialog(){
      const dialogId = "chatDialog";
      const _dialogId = `#${dialogId}`;
      const chatDiv = `<div id="${dialogId}"></div>`;

      $(chatDiv).dialog({
              width: 650,
              height: 625
          });

      $(_dialogId).dialog();
      $('#ChatContainer').appendTo(_dialogId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect React will object to this very strongly. It's better to create the jQuery dialog first (on the outside) and then render your React component inside it.

```
var $chatDiv = $("<div class='dialog'>");  //create new element
$("body").append( $chatDiv );              //add it to page
$chatDiv.dialog({                          //make a dialog
   width: 650,
   height: 625
});

ReactDOM.render( <ChatWindow />, $chatDiv[0] );   //render component inside
```